# Post Method request not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm having a problem with my code now and it seems like that the route that I specify is not found whenever I try to access it.

Route:

```
 Route::post('nniscaseassociates/pushreliever/{id}', 'NnisCaseAssociateController@pushreliever');
 Route::get('nniscaseassociates/{id}/reliever', 'NnisCaseAssociateController@reliever');
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="/nniscaseassociates/pushreliever/{{ $caseassociate->nnis_case_id }}">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
<...Fields...>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
    public function reliever($id)
    {
        //this will be nniscase id then
        $caseassociate = NnisCaseAssociate::findOrFail($id);
        //return dd($caseassociate);
        return view('nniscaseassociates.reliever', compact('caseassociate'));
    }
    public function pushreliever(Request $request, $id)
    {
            ...Statements...
            return redirect('nniscases/'.$caseassociates->nnis_case_id.'/edit');
    }
```

By the end of submitting I want to redirect to my edit page and display the changes that I made from the previous form. And this is the error that I got when click submit.
[image]

Comment: where did your URL go when you have this error? Try action="nniscaseassociates/pushreliever/{{ $caseassociate->nnis_case_id }}" insted. No slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a `PUT` request and not `POST`.

Either remove this line from your form:

```
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Or

Change your `POST` route to `PUT`:

```
Route::put
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not defined `PUT method` in your `web.php`

```
Route::put('nniscaseassociates/pushreliever/{id}', 'NnisCaseAssociateController@pushreliever');
```

in your view :

```
<form method="POST" action="/nniscaseassociates/pushreliever/{{ $caseassociate->nnis_case_id }}">
        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
<...Fields...>
</form>
```

in your controller :

```
public function pushreliever(Request $request, $id)
{
     echo $id;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should try this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('nniscaseassociates/pushreliever',[$caseassociate->nnis_case_id]) }}">
```